# Connecting with a third party C++ header file using JNA

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface, jna

I have got a third party dll file with header like below.

```
class MyClass
{
public:

    MyClass() {};
    virtual ~MyClass() {};
    int Double(int x);
};
```

I cannot connect with the dll file using JNA (as I cannot extern here). So I have created a wrapper dll. From that wrapper dll , I am trying to connect with the third party dll. wrapper dll header file (Sample.h)

```
extern "C" {
int __declspec(dllexport) Double(int x);
}
```

**wrapper dll's cpp file**

```
typedef int (__cdecl *MYPROC)(int); 
int func(int x)
{
HINSTANCE hinstLib; 
MYPROC ProcAdd; 
BOOL fFreeResult, fRunTimeLinkSuccess = FALSE; 
int result;

printf("inside the function");
// Get a handle to the DLL module.

hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("example_dll.dll")); 

// If the handle is valid, try to get the function address.

if (hinstLib != NULL) 
{ 
    ProcAdd = (MYPROC) GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "Double"); 

    // If the function address is valid, call the function.

    if (NULL != ProcAdd) 
    {
        fRunTimeLinkSuccess = TRUE;
        result = ProcAdd(x);
        printf("Result: %d", result);
    } else {
        printf("function not found");
    }
    // Free the DLL module.

    fFreeResult = FreeLibrary(hinstLib); 
} 

// If unable to call the DLL function, use an alternative.
if (! fRunTimeLinkSuccess) 
    printf("Message printed from executable\n"); 

return result; 
}
```

Using a C program(compiled by g++) I can connect with both the dll and get the data.

***But from a Java program(using JNA), I can connect with the first dll but first dll cannot connect with the second dll.***

Could anybody please enlighten me how to fix the problem? Of if there are any other way to fix it?

Comment: Might want to take a look at other tools like [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp)...

Comment: I will take a look at it. But I do not know why I cann't do it using JNA..:(. Do you know anything about it?

Comment: It only supports C, not C++, so for C++ libraries it is not easy to use.

Comment: It looks like you've properly exported `Double` as a function using C conventions, but that's going to cause problems in Java since that's the name of a class, so without special work you're not going to be able to automatically map a `Double` method in JNA to your native method.  Try changing the name of the method.

Comment: I changed the function name to getData().. It is all the same.. From Java file, it cannot execute. I think I have to go with either SWIG or JavaCPP , as suggested by Samuel Audet